# Alignment is changed while zooming webpage

Tags: html

This is my HTML file

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-image: url(Images/android_background.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div id='cssmenu' style="position:relative;   top:100px; ">
<ul>
<li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#’><span>Android</span></a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>extra</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<center>

<table  border="1" style="position:relative; top:200px; "> 
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr> 
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>  
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>   
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>  
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>  
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>  
<tr><td> Under Construction </td> </tr>
</table>

</center>

<div class="push"></div>


</div>


<div class="footer" style=" position:relative; top:300px;" >
<img src="android/Images/home_background.png" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Output :[image]

While zoomout this webpage, background and footer image alignment is changed. Output after making zoomout is:[image]

I am very new for web page designing. I don't know why this happen? can you give some solutions?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are zooming page out, but your background image isn't endless, that's why you can see the white space on the left. You can tune your CSS to repeat the background horizontally:

```
body {
  background-image: url(Images/android_background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

You also can reduce the size of the image file by croping it to be only 1 px wide. Your background will be visually the same but the website will be loading faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try boostrap responsive load. It will make your life easier.

The problem you are facing is because of hardcoded pixel values. You should try relative values in terms of %.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do much since you're using a background image.  That's a pretty easy effect to duplicate w/ css3 though.

Answer (score 0):

I was add `min-width:100%;` in the style of img tag. It was working.

Comment: What you did here is you've stretched the image to take the full width of the browser window.